# Django override startapp | startproject commands

Tags: django, django-commands

I need to create a Django Project with a different files and folder structure.
In particular I need to add 2 folders: `qqapp` and `qqproject` when creating a new app through the `startapp` command, each containing some base files.

**How can I override the base commands or add a custom one?**

My current solution is editing the base commands files (changing dir name for default folders) `django/core/management/commands/startapp|project.py,` but I think this is bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

Use [project templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4-alpha-1/#custom-project-and-app-templates) for this.

```
django-admin.py startproject --template=/path/to/my_project_template myproject
```

Answer (score 1):

there is a documentation for this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: i knew about this, but for creation custom commands we need create app and add this into INSTALLED_APPS.. or i'm wrong?

Comment: btw i want to creat startproject command.. at that moment we didin'y have project, so this not right for me i think

Comment: I looked at the source: https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/core/management/__init__.py#L71 You can install your command in to django.core, in which case you won't need an application. this is still not very clean though.

Comment: i use now something like this, it's work, but looking for nice way for this if it possible)

Comment: do you mean that you want to avoid putting your code in to django/core directory?

Comment: I think for that you will have to patch django.core.management module